# Order of automatically wrapped @Repeatable annotations

Tags: java, annotations, java-8

Before, I used to declare a wrapper annotation by hand, with an array, and then call it like so:

```
@Foos({ @Foo(0), @Foo(1), @Foo(2) })
public void bar() {}
```

Since I was making an array with the `{ ... }` initializers, it was more than clear that the order was to be the same of the declaration when I accessed this method later via Reflection.

However, when I use the new `@Repeatable` annotation from Java 8, do I have guarantee that the order will be kept?

I declared a simple set of annotations:

```
public @interface Foos {
  Foo[] value();
}

@Repeatable(Foos.class)
public @interface Foo {
 int value();
}
```

and run some tests with the most diverse scenarios:

```
@Foo(0) @Foo(1) @Foo(2)
public void bar1() {}

@Foo(2)
@Deprecated @Foo(5)
@Foo(10)
public void bar2() {}
```

and everything seems to work flawlessly (when accessing via Reflection), but I would not like to rely on undocumented stuff. It seems obvious to me that that should be the case, but I can't find it anywhere! Can anyone shed a light on this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7.5) says:

> If a declaration context or type context has multiple annotations of a repeatable annotation type T, then it is as if the context has no explicitly declared annotations of type T and one implicitly declared annotation of the containing annotation type of T.
>
> The implicitly declared annotation is called the container annotation, and the multiple annotations of type T which appeared in the context are called the base annotations. **The elements of the (array-typed) value element of the container annotation are all the base annotations in the left-to-right order in which they appeared in the context**.

(emphasis mine)

So yes, the order of the annotations in the container annotation is the same as the order of declaration of the repeatable annotations.

Comment: Thanks! Now I feel secure using this :)